# Is it possible to run aggregation on the whole dask dataframe (without using groupby)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

Pandas dataframe  offer the `aggregate`/`agg` method to do aggregation on all or a subset of columns.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
             [
                 ("1", 1, 0, 0),
                 ("2", 2, 0, 0),
                 ("3", 3, 0, 0),
                 ("4", 4, 5, 4),
                 ("5", 5, 6, 6),
                 ("6", 6, 7, 7),
           ],
    columns=("item", "att1", "att2", "att3"),
)

df.agg(["mean", "max", "sum"]) # ->
#        item  att1  att2       att3
# mean   20576   3.5   3.0   2.833333
# max        6   6.0   7.0   7.000000
# sum   123456  21.0  18.0  17.000000
```

However Dask dataframes only offer aggregations on groupby methods. Is there a way to emulate the behaviour?